# Existe algum problema em atribuir um valor a um ponteiro?

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória

Eu estou me referenciando por este site aqui [Como declarar ponteiros em C](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/03/Como-declarar-inicializar-e-usar-ponteiros-e-a-constante-NULL-em-C.html)

Normalmente quando queremos iniciar uma variável do tipo inteiro, por exemplo, fazemos `int inteiro = 4;`m mas e se fizéssemos `int *inteiro_ptr = 4;` pode implicar em alguma coisa no código ou por alguma razão não é aconselhável? Eu já fiz alguns testes e não apresentou nenhum problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int inteiro = 4;
    int *inteiro_ptr = 4;

    printf("Valor da variariavel 'inteiro': %d\n", inteiro);
    printf("Endereco da variariavel 'inteiro': %d\n", &inteiro);
    printf("Valor armazenado no ponteiro 'inteiro_ptr': %d\n", inteiro_ptr);
    printf("Endereco armazenado no ponteiro 'inteiro_ptr': %d\n\n", &inteiro_ptr);

    printf("Apos o uso dos ponteiros, vamos aponta-los para NULL\n\n");
    inteiro = NULL;
    inteiro_ptr = NULL;
    printf("Endereco armazenado no ponteiro 'inteiro': %d\n", inteiro);
    printf("Endereco armazenado no ponteiro 'inteiro_ptr': %d\n", inteiro_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O bigown já disse tudo. Só queria complementar dizendo que ,por exemplo,em `int *var_ptr;` você só está a declarar um ponteiro para um inteiro o que muitas vezes nos confunde é o * porque normalmente quando colocamos o * é para apontar o ponteiro para um certo valor. Quando faz`int *var_ptr = &var;` já está correto pois é a mesma coisa que `int *var_ptr;` e depois `var_ptr = &var;`. O meu conselho é quando quer declarar um ponteiro para uma certa variável de um certo tipo faça `int* var_ptr;`  deixei o * colado ao int invés de colado ao nome da variável penso que confunda menos.

Comment: Concordo com o @MtTech, desde que você nunca declare mais de uma variável na mesma linha, se fizer isto, dá @#$%&!*.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que procurava saber? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Se não, precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 9):

Isso está completamente errado. O que este código está fazendo é dizer que a variável `inteiro_ptr` tem o valor 4 (depois o valor 0 quando a anula), portando ela se refere à posição 4 (5o. byte) da memória virtual da sua aplicação. Isto certamente não é o que deseja e está acessando um local indevido.

Dependendo das opções de compilação, o código nem compila. Veja [no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iVf1l4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mpmnzubw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/RawPointerAssigment.c).

Uma variável do tipo ponteiro deve guardar um endereço de memória sempre. Esse endereço será usado para acessar um objeto que conterá o valor que deseja armazenar de verdade. Essa é uma forma de indireção.

Em geral o objeto referenciando é armazenado no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Nada obriga que seja lá, o exemplo da pergunta até mostra isso, mas é o mais comum.

Para alocar a memória no *heap* o mais comum é usar a função [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc). Ela requisita a memória necessária (se for o caso pede para o sistema operacional) e retorna para o código um ponteiro para essa porção de memória. Aí seu código deve colocar o valor que pretende lá no objeto alocado.

Código melhorado (não sei se faz o que desejava, mas é mais correto):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    int inteiro = 4;
    int *inteiro_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *inteiro_ptr = 4; //aqui está colocando o valor no endereço apontado pela variável

    printf("Valor da variariavel 'inteiro': %d\n", inteiro);
    printf("Endereco da variariavel 'inteiro': %p\n", (void *)&inteiro);
    printf("Valor armazenado no ponteiro 'inteiro_ptr': %d\n", *inteiro_ptr);
    printf("Endereco armazenado no ponteiro 'inteiro_ptr': %p\n\n", (void *)inteiro_ptr);

    printf("Apos o uso dos ponteiros, vamos aponta-los para NULL\n\n");
    inteiro = 0; //esta variável não é um ponteiro, quer zerá-la, faça com 0
    inteiro_ptr = NULL;
    printf("Endereco armazenado no ponteiro 'inteiro': %d\n", inteiro);
    printf("Endereco armazenado no ponteiro 'inteiro_ptr': %p\n", (void *)inteiro_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WS6PZM). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mlscnrkf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/RawPointerAssigment2.c).

Note que eu nem tentei acessar o valor de `inteiro_ptr` depois de anulá-lo, isso daria erro em tempo de execução. Tive que fazer um *cast* para atender ao requisito do [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Tem mais um monte de pequenos detalhes a serem observados no código mas acho que já foge do escopo da pergunta.