# Qual a diferença entre ponteiro para vetor e ponteiro para variável?

Tags: c, c++, variáveis, ponteiro, array

```
int A;
int* pA = 1;
int Vect[2] = {1,2};
int* pVect;

pA = &A;
*pA = 2;

pVect = Vect;
pVect[0] = 10;
```

No caso eu tenho um ponteiro para uma variável e depois para um vetor, e quero alterar seus valores pelo ponteiro. Por que existe essa divergência na passagem dos endereços (na variável eu tenho que usar o `&` e no vetor não precisa)? Isso é próprio da linguagem C?

Pelo que sei de ponteiro, ele aponta para o endereço de memória daquela variável obtido pelo `&`, mas pra vetor não precisa do `&`.

Comment: Note que `pVect` não é um ponteiro para vetor. Ele é um ponteiro para uma variável do tipo `(int)`, exatamente como `pA`. A diferença é que ele está sendo apontado para o primeiro elemento do vetor. `p = vetor` é a mesma coisa que `p = &vetor[0]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se considerar que um vetor é uma variável, nesse ponto não tem diferença.

Um ponteiro aponta para um endereço de memória, ponto. O endereço pode ser obtido de diversas formas. Uma delas é um apontamento para um vetor. Você pode acessar um vetor por um ponteiro de forma natural. A variável que acessa um vetor é um ponteiro. Sendo um ponteiro não tem por que usar o operador de "endereço de" (`&`).

Veja mais:

- [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101)
- [Qual o significado do operador "&" (e comercial) na linguagem C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101)
- [Operador & e * nas funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156278/101)
- [Como uma variável é apontada para um ponteiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91365/101)
- [Diferença entre array de char e ponteiro de char](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130792/101)
- [Ponteiro de char ou array de char?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116333/101)
- [O que é ponteiro para ponteiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92823/101)
- [Existe algum problema em atribuir um valor a um ponteiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136535/101)
- [Se array é o mesmo que ponteiro, por que um precisa ser copiado para uma variável e outro não precisa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181609/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).