# "Operador" colchetes [] na criação do arranjo em C

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, característica-linguagem, operadores

Sempre que procuro o que o operador colchetes `[]` faz, até mesmo nas tabelas que mostram todos os operadores em C, aparece que ele serve para acessar um elemento de um arranjo. Porém, não é sempre que isso acontece, como por exemplo no caso em que o arranjo ainda não existe, ou seja, na hora da criação:

```
int main()
{
    // nessa linha, eu tenho a certeza de que o colchetes não faz acesso a nada.
    void *ptrArray[100];

    // porém, nessa linha, eu sei que o colchetes faz o acesso ao 2º elemento do arranjo
    ptrArray[1];
}
```

Então, já que não é mencionado em nenhum lugar sobre o **operador** `[]` na hora da criação de arranjos, presumo eu que ele não seja um operador nesse caso. Está certo?

Como o compilador faz essa diferenciação? Eu acredito que o compilador reconheça a diferença porque ele viu que houve uma palavra chave de um tipo primitivo ou `struct` antes, no meu caso é a palavra chave `void`.

O retorno do operador `[]` é sempre um ponteiro, certo? Então, na hora da compilação, é como se `void *ptrArray[100]` fosse `void **ptrArray`, certo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nesse caso ele não é um operador, é uma sintaxe idêntica com semântica diferente. Nessa linha ele não está operando nada, está só declarando.

O compilador diferencia pelo contexto onde está. Quando ele aparece no que chamamos *lvalue* é sempre a forma de declaração. Quando aparece em *rvalue* é o operador.

*Lvalue* aí é a declaração em si, nesse contexto é o que vem antes do `=`, e o *rvalue* é uma expressão que pode ser usadas em diversos locais do código. Isso não quer dizer que pode ser usado em todos os `lvalue*. De fato precisa ser em uma declaração, isso já é uma avaliação semântica, é outro passo da compilação. Se quiser saber mais: [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101).

Obviamente isto é uma simplificação, a regra exata é bem mais complicada e pode variar de compilador para compilador, desde que cumpra tudo que a especificação manda.

`[]` é sempre uma forma de acessar um endereço por um ponteiro. E `void *ptrArray[100]` é como uma declaração de `void **ptrArray`, mas não é a mesma coisa. Veja mais em [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). Tem [vários *links* sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193507/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Eu vou usar o rascunho mais recente [N2176](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) (que encontrei aqui: http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/The_Standard) da padronização de C para responder.

Na seção [[6.7.6]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf#subsection.6.7.6), uma das partes da sintaxe de um declarador é a declaração direta (ou *direct-declarator*), que é onde a sintaxe para a declaração de arranjos está. O que interessa-nos aqui é o declarador de arranjo (*array declarator*): dada uma declaração `T D1`, se `D1` estiver em uma das seguintes formas:

> D **[** *type-qualifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> *assignment-expression*<sub>opt</sub> **]**
>
> D **[** *type-qualifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> *assignment-expression* **]**
>
> D **[** *type-qualifier-list* **static** *assignment-expression* **]**
>
> D **[** *type-qualifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> **]**

Então temos um declarador de arranjo. Perceba que os colchetes são usados apenas para indicar um declarador de arranjo, mais nada. Não há operação de subscrito<sup>1</sup> ocorrendo aqui. Por exemplo, na declaração `int a[8]`, a parte `a[8]` é um declarador de arranjo, onde `8` é o tamanho do arranjo (ou quantidade de elementos).

Se não estivermos no contexto de declaração e encontrarmos uma expressão na forma `I[N]`, onde `I` já foi declarado como um arranjo (ou ponteiro) então certamente temos a operação de subscrito ocorrendo. Por exemplo:

```
int a[8]; // Declara `a` como um arranjo de 8 elementos de tipo `int`.
a[0]; // Acessa o primeiro elemento de `a`, retornando um valor do tipo `int`.
```

Finalmente, sobre sua última dúvida em relação a equivalência entre arranjos e ponteiros: arranjos podem decair para ponteiros. Elaborando: na declaração `int a[8]`, o identificador `a` foi declarado pra ter o tipo `int[8]`. Entretanto, a expressão `a` pode muito bem resultar em um valor cujo tipo é um ponteiro.

```
void foo(int *);

int main()
{
    int a[8]; // Declara `a` tendo tipo `int[8]`.

    foo(a); // O valor que a expressão `a` em si gera terá o
            // tipo decaído para um `int *`.
}
```

Esse comportamento de decaimento é descrito na seção [[6.3.2/3]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf#subsection.6.7.6):

> Except when it is the operand of the **sizeof** operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. […]

---

<sup>1</sup> Subscrito é o nome da operação de acesso a elementos de um arranjo.