# diferença entre vet[] e *vet

Tags: c, array

Quando mando um vetor para a função, nos argumentos.. qual a diferença entre colocar

```
void funcao(int vet[])
```

e

```
void funcao(int *vet)
```

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que é duplicata, depois analiso melhor. Essa resposta aqui acho que é um ponto de partida para entender bem o assunto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193517/70

Answer (score 3):

> Qual é a diferença entre `void funcao(int vet[]) { /* ... */ }` e `void funcao(int *vet) { /* ... */ }`?

Absolutamente nenhuma.
As duas formas são 100% idênticas.

É de realçar que, em C, é impossível passar arrays como parametros a uma função (e que o compilador converte automaticamente para um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento). Com isso em mente, a segunda opção parece corresponder melhor à realidade.

Answer (score -1):

Sua pergunta é se existe diferença entre `vet[]` e `*vet`. Bom, a resposta é que nenhuma.

#### Segundo a apostila [IME USP](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Ehitoshi/introducao/19-vetor_ponteiro.pdf):

**Vetores**

Vetores são estruturas indexadas utilizadas para armazenar dados de um mesmo
tipo: int, char, float ou double. Por exemplo, a declaração
`int v[80]; /∗ declara um vetor de inteiros de nome v com 80 casas ∗/`

Cada casa do vetor `v` (ou seja, `v[0], v[1], ..., v[79]`) é um inteiro. Além disso, cada casa tem um endereço
associado (ou seja, `&v[0], &v[1], ..., &v[79]`).

Uma pergunta que poderíamos fazer é como um vetor fica armazenado na memória. A organização das variáveis
na memória depende de como o sistema operacional faz gerenciamento da memória. Em geral, para ser mais
eficiente, o sistema operacional tende a colocar as vari´aveis sucessivamente. Assim, a alocaçãao do vetor na
memória é feita de forma sucessiva, ou seja, da maneira como ilustrada na figura acima: `v[0]` antes de `v[1]`, que
por sua vez antes de `v[2]` e assim por diante. Assim, as variveis declaradas como

```
int v [80]; /∗ declara um vetor de inteiros de nome v com 80 casas ∗/
int n , m;
```

poderiam ser alocadas de forma sucessiva como

[image: alocação de vetores]

Na linguagem C não existe verificação de índices fora do vetor. Quem deve controlar o uso correto dos índices é o programador. Além disso, o acesso utilizando um índice errado pode ocasionar o acesso de outra variável
na memória. No exemplo acima, `v[80]` acessaria a variável n. Se o acesso à memória é indevido você recebe a mensagem “segmentation fault”.

**Vetores e Ponteiros**

A implementação de vetores em C está bastante interligada com a de ponteiros visando a facilitar a manipulação
de vetores. Considere a seguinte declaração de variáveis:

```
int v[80]; /∗ declara um vetor de inteiros de nome v com 80 casas ∗/
int *p;
```

que aloca na mem´oria algo do tipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podemos utilizar a sintaxe normal para fazer um ponteiro apontar para uma casa do vetor:

```
p = &v [2]; /∗ p aponta para a casa de índice 2 de v ∗/
```

Mas podemos utilizar a **sintaxe especial para ponteiros e vetores**, junto com as operações para ponteiros:

- Podemos fazer um ponteiro apontar para o início do vetor v fazendo
  `p = v;`

  É a única situação em que o nome do vetor tem sentido sem os colchetes. O comando acima equivale a
  fazer `p = &v[0];`
- Podemos usar a sintaxe de vetores (`nome_do_vetor[índice]`) com o ponteiro. Assim, se fizermos
  `p = v;`
  podemos acessar o elemento que est´a na casa i de v fazendo p[i], ou seja, ambos p[i] e v[i] acessam a
  casa i do vetor v. Exemplo:

```
i = 3;
p = v ; /∗ p aponta para v[0]. Equivale a fazer p = &v[0] ∗/
p [ i ] = 4; /∗ equivale a fazer v[i] = 4 ∗/
```

Mas se fazemos
`p = &v [3];`

então, `p[0]` é o elemento `v[3]`, `p[1]` é o elemento `v[4]`, `p[2]` é o elemento `v[5]`, e assim por diante.

- Podemos fazer algumas operac¸˜oes com ponteiros. Considere a seguinte declaração:

```
int ∗p , ∗q , n , v[50];
float ∗x , y[20];
```

1. Quando somamos 1 a um ponteiro para int (por exemplo, p) ele passa a apontar para o endereço de memória logo após a memória reservada para este inteiro. Exemplo, se `p = &v[4]`, então `p+1` é o endereço de `v[5]`, `p+2` é o endereço de `v[6]`, `p+i` é o endereço de `v[4+i]`.
   Dessa forma, `∗p` (vai para onde o p está apontando) é o `v[4]`. Portanto, `v[4] = 3` é a mesma coisa que
   fazer `∗p = 3`. Como `p+1` é o endereço de `v[5]`, então `∗(p+1)` é `v[5]`. Assim, `v[5] = 10` é a mesma coisa que fazer `∗(p+1) = 10`.
2. Se somamos 1 a um ponteiro para float (por exemplo x) ele avança para o endereço após este float.
   Por exemplo, se `x=&y[3]`, então `x+1` é o endereço de y`[4]` e `x+i` é o endereço de `y[3+i]`.
3. Somar ou subtrair um inteiro de um ponteiro:

```
p = &v [22]; q = &v [30];
p = p − 4 ; q++;
∗( p+2) = 3 ; ∗q = 4;
```

Qual índice de v recebe 3? Qual índice de v recebe 4?<sup>1</sup>

Subtrair dois ponteiros:

```
p = &v [20]; q = &v [31];
n = q − p ; /∗ número inteiro : a diferença entre os índices, neste caso, 11. ∗
```

<sub>Fonte: [IME.USP](https://www.ime.usp.br/~hitoshi/introducao/19-vetor_ponteiro.pdf)</sub>

Comment: E qual é a sua conclusão sobre as diferenças das declarações?